# Powershell, Invoke-WebRequest and the downloaded content

Tags: powershell

I often do the same mistake over again: in powershell, I run

```
wget http://example.com
```

instead of

```
wget http://example.com -OutFile somename
```

and when the command (`wget` aka `Invoke-WebRequest`) is done executing, the downloaded file is stored... apparently, nowhere.

**Q:** Is there a way to store the downloaded content *post-factum*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you dont specify -outfile, it is only returned to the pipeline to be used in next Statement.